# how to resolve the javascipt code using cheerio data-scraping

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio, request-promise

I have watched the video on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqGq9MTSt7g&t=1510s) then I want to practice the code in a different way.
I want to extract the data from [imdbdata](https://www.imdbdata.com) website then how to resolve the issue JS code.

**Getting data from IMDB website**

```
    const option = {
        uri: "https://www.imdb.com/chart/moviemeter/?ref_=nv_mv_mpm",
        headers: {
            Accept: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        },
        json: true,
        transform: (body) => cheerio.load(body),
    };
```

**request-promise code**

```
    await rp(option)
        .then(($) => {
            process.stdout.write("loading...\n");
            let table = [];
            $("tbody[class='lister-list'] tr").each((i, el) => {
                //self call function
                process.stdout.write(`.`);
                let link =
                    "https://www.imdb.com" +
                    $(el).find("td[class='titleColumn'] a").attr("href");
                goToNextPage(link, table);
            });
            console.table(table);
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

**I have called the function goToNextPage from request-promise JS code with parameters**

```
const goToNextPage = (link, table) => {
    let $ = cheerio.load(link);
    let title = $("div[class='title_wrapper'] > h1").text().trim(),
        ratingValue = $("div[class='ratingValue'] > strong > span")
            .text()
            .trim(),
        director = $("div[class='credit_summary_item'] > a")
            .first()
            .text()
            .trim(),
        filmType = $("div[class='subtext'] > a")
            .not('a[title="See more release dates"]')
            .text()
            .replace(/([A-Z])/g, " $1")
            .trim();
    table.push({
        title,
        director,
        filmType,
        ratingValue,
    });
};
```

[Why does output is only empty data showing from the console.table(table)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCb4b.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your code generates the dots with:

```
process.stdout.write(`.`);
```

Remove that part of code and you won't have dots.